# Automatically update related values in a new struct in c++

Tags: c++, struct, custom-data-type

I want to define a new data type based on my need and when I update a variable, I want the other variables to be update without calling a new function.

Consider this:

```
struct myNode {
    short rows;
    short cols;
    short channels;
    Mat data;
};
```

Imagine, I'm updating `Mat data`. I want `rows,cols and channels` to be updated automatically. I can write another method to update but it is unnecessary to call new method everytime I update `data`.

I couldn't find anything about it. How can I do this?

Comment: How about you get rid of `rows`, `cols`, and `channels` and instead have `data.getRows()`, `data.getCols()`, and `data.getChannels()`?

Comment: Either you will need to call another method, or you could write an assignment method for `data`. Which is another method. I don't think it gets any more automatic than that.

Comment: @Barry, I edited the question. The structure is just sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use `c++` you can use `setter` function of `data` and update `data` through the setter `function`.

Sample code may looks

```
struct myNode{
    short rows;
    short cols;
    short channels;

    Mat data;
    void setData(const Mat& d)
    {
        //set Rows, cols, channels according to your wish.
        this->data = d;
    }
};
```

Better solution  with `class`

```
class myNode{
    short rows;
    short cols;
    short channels;
    Mat data;
    public:
    void setData(const Mat& d)
    {
        //set Rows, cols, channels according to your wish.
        this->data = d;
    }
    Mat getData()
    {
        return this->data;
    }
};
```

Actually in `c++` `class` and `struct` are equivalent except `struct` have default public members  and classes have default private members.

Comment: It should be a class, with private data, if the data should always remain in a consistent state.  Otherwise, any code anywhere could alter any piece of it by itself.

Comment: Yes, but if OP try to stick with struct then he can use this.

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman, this is what I was looking for but I didn't get the problem?

Comment: @Lorehead, could you tell a bit more detailed about how it can be altered?

Comment: You may want to use `const Mat&` depending if it is expensive to copy.

Comment: If you'd rather, you can get the equivalent result with a `struct` by declaring only `Mat` as `private:`

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman this is what I exactly wanted, thanks. after making some values `private`, it works as I wanted.